# query random image from Wordpress Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, image, random

If i am using the the plugin "Enhanced Media Library" and i want to display a random image, can i somehow use a WP_query to do this?

With the plugin activated this is how my media library looks like: 
[image]

I have created a category called: "imgfront", and i then want to display a random image from this category on a specific page. I tried the following query:

```
           $image = new WP_Query( 
            array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                'media_category' => 'imgfront',
                'posts_per_page' => '1', 
                'orderby' => 'rand',   
                )
            );  

        if( $image->have_posts() ){
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->posts[0], 'full' );
            ?><img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>"> <?php
        }
```

The query does noot seem to return any images though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672401/get-random-post-in-wordpress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random post in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672401/get-random-post-in-wordpress)

Comment: Also you must be change `WP_Query` and add `post_type=>attachment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, I am an author of the Enhanced Media Library (thanks for using it!). Media taxonomies created by the plugin, including Media Categories, are just ordinary WordPress custom taxonomies. So, everything related to WordPress taxonomies works for them equally well.

Taxonomy request should be as described in [WP_Query Taxonomy Params](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'imgfront',
        ),
    ),
);
$image = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But I would've better used `term_id` instead of `slug` in this case.